# Replace in a string with unicode Django and python3.7

Tags: django, python-3.x, unicode

So iIhave this charfield in Django:

```
class Rue(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
```

Here is my script :

```
print(rue.name)
rue.name = rue.name.replace("Ã%Coles","Ecoles")
print(rue.name)
rue.save()
```

I want to correct the error of an imported file, and clean the database.
I would like to replace the "Ã%Coles" by "Ecoles".

But the output is :

```
Rue Des Ã%Coles
Rue Des Ã%Coles
```

How to clean this ? i want to replace "Ã%Coles" by "Ecoles"

Comment: Type `print(repr(rue.name.encode('latin-1'))` before and after. That might clarify exactly what you have in the string. I would have expected that to output 'Rue Des \xc3\x89coles' rather than the 'Rue Des \xc3%Coles' you say you have if it got inadvertently latin-1 decoded instead of utf-8 decoded (which seems a likely cause).

Comment: Is the html document using latin-1 instead of utf-8? Check if there's a meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: If your data has been saved in the database with an incorrect encoding, this library can help you clean it up again. https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like broken encoding, and the `%C` you are seeing is not a percent followed by a C, but instead one single control character that probably got changed further.

on my system:

```
>>> print('Écoles'.encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1'))
Ã coles
```

To fix this single problem, you could probably do:

```
broken_e = 'É'.encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1')
rue.name = rue.name.replace(broken_e, 'E')
rue.save()
```

Comment: If you add `repr` in there, non-printing characters and invalid code points will displayed as unicode escape codes  `print(repr('Écoles'.encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1')))` => `'Ã\x89coles'`. The `\x89` code point is unused in unicode and is also unused in latin-1 / iso-8859-1.